# Bootstrap (4 Alpha) Date Drop down only working in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am creating some forms using reference bootstrap 4 examples:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2011-08-19" id="example-date-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

When I test in Chrome the drop down seems to be working as expected, but in both Firefox and IE11 I am having no luck using it as is.

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hjhcvmo5/

Any advice or work arounds available for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE and FF do not yet support the html `input[date]`, Chromes does and that's why you see it, you will have to use a datepicker plugin. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the information @JuanC. Very disappointing :(